# java member variables' visibility between parent class and child class

Tags: java

I created the following code:

```
class Father {  
    int num = 10;  

    public void setNum(int num) {  
        this.num = num;  
    }  
    public int getNum() {  
        return num;  
    }  
}  
class Child extends Father {  

    public void show() {  
        System.out.println(num);            // 20
        System.out.println(this.num);       // 20   
        System.out.println(super.num);      // 20 
    }  
}  
public class Test001 {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Child child = new Child();  
        child.setNum(20);  
        child.show();  
    }
}
```

My question is why super.num will print 20? I think super.num is 10. Because variable num is unrelated between Father and Child. The variable num in Child is just a copy from Father. who can tell me why?

Comment: Since `Child`doesn't even have `num` in your code, where do you think it is coming from?

Comment: There is only one member variable `num` and it's in class `Father`, there is no such variable in class `Child`.

Comment: Thanks very much , I have got it

Answer (score 4):

Child class inherits num from Parent class. It does not have a copy, but is truly the owner of this class.

I will give you example - Lets say parent is Fruit and num is taste - when a clild (say apple) inherits fruit - it owns the property taste. Even if "taste" was defaulted to "neutral" - apple will change taste to "appleTaste" and whenever you eat (i.e. print apple.taste) even using super, it will output "appleTaste" and not the default taste value. It is important to understand that "num" or "taste" belong to "instance" and thus, the final instance "apple" or "child" decides the value.

Gave you this example from real world to understand it via analogy and something that you can imagine.

Answer (score 2):

> The variable num in Child is just a copy from Father.

No it absolutely is not. `num` is defined in the parent class `Father`. It's accessible by `Child` due to the inheritance.

When you write `child.setNum(20);` it's actually the function in `Father` that is used.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I have made a common mistake . I also have a question . If i add a raw code that is  System.out.println(super.getClass().getName())  in show function . it will print Child  not Father,  why????

Answer (score 1):

> Because variable `num` is unrelated between `Father` and `Child`

That is not true. `Child` extends the *definition* of `Father`, which *includes* the member `num`. It's accessible from child-classes, so they are allowed to change it's value (directly), or by calling the setter method (which is also accessible from sub-classes of `Father`)

Answer (score 0):

super.num will print 20 because those keyword "super" indicates the refernce of Parent Class,it is instantiating the sublclass.
e.g.It is equivalent of ParentClass p = new ChildClass();

The refernce(p) is of Parent Class but it is still pointing to Subclass object.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `num` is **not** a copy of the variable in the parent class.  It is **inherited** from it.

Note that `num` is an instance variable.  One copy of it exists per instance of `Father`.  Because `Child extends Father`, every instance of `Child` is an instance of `Father`, but with the added functionality defined by the `Child` class.